# Google script for generating PDF, how to set to save to specific folder?

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation

I have the below script working fine to generate a pdf from my spreadsheet, however it saves the pdf in the root of my google drive. How can i make it save to a particular folder?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
*/ 
// Config
// ------

// 1. Create a GDoc template and put the ID here
var TEMPLATE_ID = '164rlZ1XNJovaQAO1-OF2fNLWNEhbqEImNCJe4Ohk7tY'


// 2. You can specify a name for the new PDF file here, or leave empty to use the 
// name of the template or specify the file name in the sheet
var PDF_FILE_NAME = ''

// 3. If an email address is specified you can email the PDF
var EMAIL_SUBJECT = 'Quote Test'
var EMAIL_BODY = 'Test'

// Constants
// ---------

// You can pull out specific columns values 
var FILE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME = 'File Name'
var EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME = 'Email'

/**
 * Eventhandler for spreadsheet opening - add a menu.
 */

function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp
    .getUi()
    .createMenu('Create Quote')
    .addItem('Create Quote', 'createPdf')
    .addToUi()

} // onOpen()

/**  
 * Take the fields from the active row in the active sheet
 * and, using a Google Doc template, create a PDF doc with these
 * fields replacing the keys in the template. The keys are identified
 * by having a <<,>> either side, e.g. <<Name>>.
 *
 * @return {Object} the completed PDF file
 */

function createPdf() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()

  if (TEMPLATE_ID === '') {

    ui.alert('TEMPLATE_ID needs to be defined in code.gs')
    return
  }

  // Set up the docs and the spreadsheet access

  var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy(),
      copyId = copyFile.getId(),
      copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId),
      copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection(),
      activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      numberOfColumns = activeSheet.getLastColumn(),
      activeRowIndex = activeSheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex(),
      activeRow = activeSheet.getRange(activeRowIndex, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
      headerRow = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
      columnIndex = 0,
      headerValue,
      activeCell,
      ID = null,
      recipient = null

  // Replace the keys with the spreadsheet values and look for a couple
  // of specific values

  for (;columnIndex < headerRow[0].length; columnIndex++) {

    headerValue = headerRow[0][columnIndex]
    activeCell = activeRow[0][columnIndex]

    copyBody.replaceText('<<' + headerValue + '>>', activeCell)

    if (headerValue === FILE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME) {

      ID = activeCell

    } else if (headerValue === EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME) {

      recipient = activeCell
    }
  }

  // Create the PDF file, rename it if required, delete the doc copy
  // and email it

  copyDoc.saveAndClose()

  var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs('application/pdf'))  

  if (PDF_FILE_NAME !== '') {

    newFile.setName(PDF_FILE_NAME)

  } else if (ID !== null){

    newFile.setName(ID)
  }

  copyFile.setTrashed(true)

  if (recipient !== null) {

    MailApp.sendEmail(
      recipient, 
      EMAIL_SUBJECT, 
      EMAIL_BODY,
      {attachments: [newFile]})
  }

  ui.alert('New PDF file created in the root of your Google Drive ' + 
        'and emailed to ' + recipient)

} // createPdf()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Google Script doesn't have a way to just move a file, you either need to [add it to a directory](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addFile(File)) or [make a copy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String,Folder)) of it in the directory that you want it to end up in.

You could do something like

```
Folder folder = DriveApp.createFolder("PDF");
folder.addFile(newFile);
```

or

```
Folder folder = DriveApp.createFolder("PDF");
newFile.makeCopy(folder);
```

Then you should be able to delete *newFile* so that you are only left with the file in a directory. This assumes you want to use an existing directory, you could do something similar with a directory that already exists by searching for the directory by [ID](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFolderById(String)) or [name](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFoldersByName(String)).